# TFS 2017 Variable Group shared between projects

Tags: tfs

Using TFS 2017 Update 3, we've defined a variable group in project A, security is setup to share with "Project Collection Valid Users" as "User". When trying to Link Variable Group from Project B, the list is empty.

[Link Variable Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaYAa.jpg)

Any idea?

Note that I've also configured security directly on my user account which is team member of both projects... no success

Microsoft documentation does not contain any sharing information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/variable-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Build and release definitions, along with all associated stuff (like task groups and variable groups) are scoped at the Team Project level. This is one of many reasons why it's recommended to keep everything within a single team project.

Comment: This is still correct as of July 2018.  Vote here to allow sharing: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31237822-library-of-variable-and-task-groups-shared-between